# Generic method return type - compilation error

Tags: java, generics

Given this code sample:

```
class A {

}

public class TestGenerics {

    private static <T extends A> T failsToCompile() {
        return new A();
    }

    private static <T extends A> T compiles(T param) {
        return param;
    }

}
```

how come the first method doesn't compile, but the second one does?

The error is:

> Incompatible types. Required: T. Found: A

Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is to return a concrete instance of a sub-type (for example of class B, that extends A). Sort of a factory method.

**Edit**: OK, for those who downvoted, I decided to elaborate a bit further. See the updated example, which no longer uses String (yes I'm aware that String is final, no need to state the obvious)

**Edit 2**: alternative version of the question:

How would you implement this method so that it compiles (without unchecked casts and warnings)?

```
abstract <T extends A> T failsToCompile();
```

**Edit 3**: Here's a code sample closer to the problem I'm trying to solve:

```
class Foo { }
class Bar extends Foo { }
class A<T extends Foo> { }
class B extends A<Bar> { }
public class TestGenerics {

    private static <T extends Foo> A<T> failsToCompile() {
        return new B();
    }

}
```

Here, the method return type is `A<T>`. Considering that `T` is defined as a *Foo or its subclass*, and the definition of B is as follows: `B extends A<Bar>`, why can't I just return `new B()`? I guess the problem comes down to the fact that you can't assign `List<Animal> dList = new ArrayList<Dog>();` and I understand why. But is there an elegant solution to this?

Comment: The value `""` is not of type `T`. It's unclear what you're asking. If you have a return type `T`, you need to return a value of type `T`. Are you asking how to get a value of that type? In what context??

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Why not? Any value of type `String` or its sub-types (which are not acceptable, since it's final, I'm very aware of that, I just used it as a placeholder) should be allowed. As I explained in the comment to the answer below, I want to be able to return a value that is a subclass of any given class. There was no need to downvote - I've provided a concrete example, error message and a very simple question. Not sure what context you're missing.

Comment: What's with downvotes? I haven't used SO in a while, but always thought it was a friendly community that helps each other. Is it a shame to ask a question these days?

Comment: Because if you have `class B extends A` and write `B b = failsToCompile()`, it couldn't work, because `new A()` is not compatible with `B`, and the compiler knows this.

Comment: What does friendliness have to do with this? The downvotes are meant to indicate that a question is unclear or otherwise not useful. That was the case here. Within the method, you have no way of knowing what type was inferred for the type parameter `T` at the method''s callsite.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: I think jFrenetic just misunderstood some aspects of java generics and asked why his code doesn't compile. IMHO the problem he's showing in the current version of his question was already clear in the first version and got answered by Elliott Frisch. Anyway, I'd bet that this is a duplicate...

Comment: The only way to implement `<T extends A> T failsToCompile()` so it compiles without warnings is `return null;`.

Comment: @shmosel ... or throw an exception, so I was thinking... This is very inconvenient.

Comment: It's inconvenient that you can't cast `Integer` to `Date`. But if you're trying to do that, there's probably a deeper problem with your code. The real question is why you're trying to do that in the first place and whether there's another means of accomplishing your goal.

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring the fact that `String` is `final` (so you can't have a sub-class of `String`), you can pass the generic class `Class<T>` into the method for the generic case. Like,

```
private static <T extends String> T get(Class<T> cls) 
            throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return cls.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: I used `String` as a placeholder. It could be any class. Essentially, I just want to be able to return an instance of a concrete type.

Comment: @jFrenetic And I have answered exactly that. Because of *type erasure*, you need to pass the `Class<T>` somewhere.

Comment: <T extends A> just restricts what type T my be. It doesn't say that T is any subclass of A. Your methods must therefore exactly return type T. While T might be instantiated to class A, your methods are still generic and therefore must return T. Generics in Java are highly confusing due to type erasure and many things that look logical won't work. Elliott Frisch shows you a solution for your problem (I think it's actually **the** solution).

Comment: @sruetti I just don't get it why I can't use A when T is a return type, but apparently I can pass new A() if T is a parameter.

Answer (score 4):

I'm trying to elaborate my comment a bit more into an answer to the "why".

What you're showing in your question are generic methods (and not generic types), see e.g. [Oracles "The Java™ Tutorials", Generic Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html).

#### Reasoning

Let's consider the explicit call for the working method: `TestGenerics.<A>compiles(new A());`

This instantiates the generic type `T` of your method call to class `A`. Remember that type erasure removes all these funky generic types when compiling, that the JVM doesn't see generic types and that the compiler handles generics. The compiler knows now, that you want to call the method with the generic type `T` "set" to class `A`. From that, it can deduct that the returned type is also of class `A` (as `T` is returned according to the methods code and as `T` is instantiated to `A`). That's all you gain here from using generics.

You can remove the `<A>` from your method call and make it look like an "ordinary" method call, as the compiler can deduct that `T` has to be `A`: `TestGenerics.compiles(new A());`

Let's look at `TestGenerics.<B>compiles(new B());` with `class B extends A {}`. As above, the compiler knows that this method call will return an object of class `B`.

Now imagine the (not compiling) code `TestGenerics.<B>compiles(new A());`. The compiler will throw an error as the object passed to the method is not of type `B`. Otherwise the method would return an object of class `A` - but the  generic type asserts that the method returns here an object of type`B`.
That's actually equivalent to the example (`B b = failsToCompile()`) Andreas gave in his comment.

Until you instantiate a generic type - even if you set bounds (like `T extends A`) - it doesn't have a class type. You therefore can't return a concrete class, as this would not satisfy the generic type parameter.

#### Pizza Example

Just for fun, let's try to make a real world example for above reasoning: Pizza. For the sake of the example, let's assume that every Pizza is a subtype of the Margherita, i.e. you add ingredients to a Margherita to get your favorite other pizza.

```
class PizzaMargherita {};

class PizzaProsciutto {
  PizzaProsciutto() {
    super(); 
    addIngredient(new Prosciutto());
  }
}
```

Your `compiles()` method now bakes the pizza:

```
public static <P extends Margherita> P bake(P pizza) {
  heat(pizza); 
  return pizza;
}
```

Bake a Margherita and get a (baked) Margherita out of your oven, bake a Prosciutto and get a Prosciutto.

Now think of this:

```
public static <P extends Margherita> P doesntBake(P pizza) {
  return new PizzaMargherita();
}
```

An oven always returning a Margherita, independent of what you put into it ?!? The compiler doesn't approve that.

-> You need the concrete pizza to bake it or you need a workaround, like the type token:

```
public static <P extends Margherita> P bakePizza(Ingredients<P> ingredient) {
  P pizza = buildPizza(ingredients);
  return bake(pizza);
}
```

#### Workaround type token

You have to use a runtime-type token as @Elliott Frisch shows in his answer:

```
private static <T extends A> T failedToCompile(Class<T> c)
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return c.newInstance();
}
```

You can't instantiate a generic type - `new T()` doesn't work, as the JVM doesn't know anything about the generic type `T`. What you're looking for in edit 2 therefore doesn't work. But `TestGenerics.<A>failedToCompile(A.class);` works, as `A.class` is part of the java byte code.

#### Workaround type token & generic class

Depending on your specific requirements, a generic factory class might help you:

```
class Factory<T extends A> {
  private final Class<T> typeToken;
  public Factory(Class<T> typeToken) {
    this.typeToken = typeToken;
  }

  public T build()
        throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    return this.typeToken.newInstance();
  }
}
```

You will still need some form of Map to get the correct factory to build the class you need, but you can now use whatever is available at the point where you need to create the Object of type T.

```
Map<String, Factory<?>> factories = new HashMap<>();
Map<DAO, Factory<?>> factories = new HashMap<>();
Map<ValueObject, Factory<?>> factories = new HashMap<>();
factories.get(valueObjectTypeA);
```

Comment: > `You therefore can't return a concrete class`
Thanks for the effort, but the question remains - what CAN I return? Look at my 2nd edit to see what I mean. Oh, and no need to explain the basics, I know well about type erasure and that it's a generic method. I was more confused as to why `new A()` cannot be considered as a valid substitution for `T` in this case, to which Andreas actually correctly replied.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to tell you: Your method can **only** return exactly **T** and nothing else. Or as the answer to the linked question states: "T is a type that extends A but is a unknown sub class of A. Returning A raises a compiler error, as it is only one specific sub class of T." As long as you don't know what T is, you can't return a concrete class, only T. You therefore have to sneak T into your method using a type token.

Answer (score 1):

Others have clearly explained why the `failsToCompile` method doesn't compile. Andreas has even shown an example...

As to how to circumvect this, I think you should consider using a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), which is just the factory you need:

```
private static <T extends A> T nowItCompilesFine(Supplier<? extends T> factory) {
    return factory.get();
}
```

And you call it:

```
A a = nowItCompilesFine(() -> new A());
```

Or using a reference to a constructor:

```
A a = nowItCompilesFine(A::new);
```

Same with any descendant of `A`:

```
class Child extends A { }

List<Supplier<? extends A>> factories = Arrays.asList(A::new, Child::new);

Supplier<? extends A> factoryA = factories.get(0);

A a1 = nowItCompilesFine(factoryA);

Supplier<? extends A> factoryChild = factories.get(1);

A a2 = nowItCompilesFine(factoryChild);

System.out.println(a2.getClass().getSimpleName()); // Child
```

Comment: This looks great, but at the calling method I don't know the actual type. I was going to implement this as a factory method which would determine an instance to return based on an argument passed.

Comment: What I'm saying is that in your example it's the calling method that should pass a method reference to the correct type. And in my case, the calling method doesn't have a knowledge of whether it's `A::new` or `B::new`, etc.

Comment: @jFrenetic I understand that. But you can use a `Supplier<? extends A>`, that's what I've shown in my edit. I.e. you could have a `Map<String, Supplier<? extends A>>` and choose the supplier by name...

Comment: I guess, your example could work if `nowItCompilesFine` is not the factory method itself, but rather a private helper method, which gets invoked by a factory method to instantiate a target type. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @jFrenetic Now that I've carefully read your comments, I realize you don't need the method to be generic at all. Just return `A` and let the method accept a `String` or whatever argument you need to determine the concrete class.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated. I've tried to come up with the simplest example possible. I'll try to post the real problem I'm trying to implement later today.  But in a nutshell, the return type (A in my example) is a paratemeterized type itself. If I use just A, I get a raw type warning. If I use A<B, C> I get this **Incompatible Types** error...

Comment: Btw, how is your example better than accepting a parameter of type T, and then simply returning it? Then it could've been called like this `A a = nowItCompilesFine(new A())`, `Child child = nowItCompilesFine(new Child())`. Pretty much the same as what you're doing with the function.

Comment: @jFrenetic the difference is that the supplier can also be a method, or a static factory method, etc

Comment: @jFrenetic if your type `A` is a parameterized type, you need to pass a type token as an argument. `Supplier` is useful here, because you can have a `Supplier<A<Integer, String>>`.

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate what you mean by passing a type token as an argument? Also, see my **edit 3** where I posted the closest to real problem code sample. Thanks.

Comment: @jFrenetic see type token [here](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained)

Comment: @jFrenetic for your 3rd edit, you need two generic type variables: `private static <T extends Foo, S extends A<T>> S nowItCompiles() { ... }`. But still, that would be unsafe and you would need to pass a `TypeToken<S>` as an argument.

Comment: Ah, that's not a part of JDK, I might not be able to use it. Crap, that gets too complicated, I've always hated generics in Java. They only scale for very primitive use cases. Every time you need to do something more advanced, the code gets bloated with them and is basically unreadable.

Comment: @jFrenetic yeah, I know what you mean... Just take the idea of the type token , you can easily create one yourself