# Java Generics - Why returning super class instance gives compile error

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Hi the following code gives compile error but I do not understand why.

```java
class SomeClass <T extends BaseClass> {
    T method(T x) {
        return x;                   // OK
    }
    
    T method() {
        return new BaseClass();    // compile error
    }
}
```

The error says requires `T` but provided `BaseClass`.
And similarly this one:

```java
class SomeClass {
    <T extends BaseClass> T method(T x) {
        return x;                          // OK
    }
    
    <T extends BaseClass> T method() {
        return new BaseClass();           // compile error
    }
}
```

I know that it can be resolved like this:

```java
class SomeClass <T extends BaseClass> {
    T method(T x) {
        return x;                       // OK
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    T method() {
        return (T) new BaseClass();    // OK
    }
}
```

But may I have some explanation on why this is not allow?

Comment: what does your error tell you?

Comment: @Stultuske It says says requires `T` but provided `BaseClass`.

Comment: well, that should tell you enough. Each T is a BaseClass, but BaseClass is not a T.

Comment: Check the answer at - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792032/generic-method-return-type-compilation-error

Comment: Expanding on Stultuske's comment: assume you have a `SomeClass<SpecialClass>`. Now you (and the compiler) expect  `method()` to return an instance of `SpecialClass` but it doesn't. See the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's just how inheritance works. Say you have a superclass A, and it has subclasses B and C. Now imagine your method accepts a parameter of type A and returns an object of type B. Your method would accept objects of type C as a parameter, but you couldn't return them because they are not of type B, even though both B and C are subclasses of A.